# How to find pdf of the values inside an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, entropy

i have an array named X 1x100 with some real values .I want to find the pdf(probability density function)
in order to find the entropy of X next .
But i dont really know how to find the pdf of X.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want the _empirical_ pdf (also called the _sample_ pdf)? That's just a histogram. Note that with only `100` samples it's not going to be very accurate

Comment: i have this type :h(X)=-1/Ν*Σlog2(fx(Xi)) and the sum goes from i=1...N where N are the 100 samples i guess

Comment: To compute the entropy you need the histogram. The histogram is an estimate of the PDF.

Comment: There are better methods to estimate the PDF than the histogram. If you have access to a university library, check B.W. Silverman *Density estimation for statistics and data analysis* Chapman & Hall/CRC 1998. In particular the kernel method (Chapter 3)